# Microsoft Bot Framework V4 how to get current executing dialogset ID

Tags: c#, botframework, bots

My problem is when executing the prompts as part of the waterfall dialog, I need the current executing prompt dialog Id. My code is as follows:

```
var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
{
        CallConfirmAsync,
        SimilarProductAsync,
        SatisfiedPreviouslyAsync,
};
AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog("productenquiry", waterfallSteps));
AddDialog(new ConfirmPrompt("call"));
AddDialog(new ConfirmPrompt("similar"));
AddDialog(new TextPrompt("previous"));
```

And my methods for the prompt dialogs are:

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> CallConfirmAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return await stepContext.PromptAsync("call", new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Did u make a phone call to user ?") });
}

private async Task<DialogTurnResult> SimilarProductAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return await stepContext.PromptAsync("similar", new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("similar stuff ?") });
}

private async Task<DialogTurnResult> SatisfiedPreviouslyAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // now here, depending on the current dialogid i.e., Similar/call , I need to do 
    // some actions
}
```

Can anyone please help me here how to get the current prompt dialogid to write my code on the condition

Comment: This is normally as simple as `stepContext.ActiveDialog.Id` but I'm pretty confused by your question and I'm wondering if you understand how dialogs work. It sounds like you're expecting `SatisfiedPreviouslyAsync` to follow either "call" or "similar", but it's the last step in the waterfall and it can only every follow "similar" right? How could it possibly ever follow "call"?

Comment: I resolved it by debugging. I changed the methods. I am a beginner. Thank you

Comment: Would you like to post your answer?